# Supplying input for Python from PHP

Tags: php, python, shell-exec

I want to send data from PHP to Python. I have this PHP code:

```
shell_exec ("sudo python /python/ba10e.py >/dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

Sending data to Python works, but when the Python program asks for input:

> The money that you input is incorrect, you want to continue?

There are two choices, "Y" and "N", but how am I going to be able to send commands to Python, such as "Y"? Is it possible to do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

Comment: can you explain me? @JoranBeasley